# How to report the custom checkstyle report in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, checkstyle

I have my own check style reports generated in xml. I want to report the result in Azure Pipeline as I am migrating to it from Jenkins.
Is there any plugin which I can use, which gets the check style xml report as an input and publishes in Azure pipeline

Comment: Hi, if you think the below answer has help, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If they have the same demand with you, they would refer to this answer:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any plugin which I can use, which gets the check style xml
>   report as an input and publishes in Azure pipeline?

Need to say that sorry, there hasn't such additionally plugin can installed in Azure Devops to used to publish the CheckStyle files. Because in Azure Devops, there has tasks that already integrated with CheckStyle: `Maven/Gradle`.

[image]

If you want to publish the CheckStyle resport in Azure pipeline, until now, as workaroud we recommend you used is build the repos in Azure Devops. Then add `Maven/Gradle` tasks to finish the standalone static analysis and generate the CheckStyle report.

But I think it would be a very good feature if VSTS can expand this feature independently into it, instead of using Maven or Gradle task in pipeline. Because add additionally task will make pipeline looks very bloated. Fortunately, there has another users has the same demand with you, and has raised such feature suggestion on our official suggestion forum recently: [Publish static analysis result task](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/740428/publish-static-analysis-result-task.html). You can vote and comment it there, thus our Product Team can collect and evaluate priorities. Then would consider to take into our Sprint RoadMap.

Comment: The Run Checkstyle tooltip indicates that the default Sun checks will be used. Do you now if it will take the custom checkstyle configuration I configured in the maven checkstyle plugin located in my `pom.xml` file?